# how to insert datatable entries into excels sheet

Tags: c#

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, (i + 1)] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    }
    excel.Columns.AutoFit();
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
    {
        // to do: format datetime values before printing
        for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < dataTable.Columns.Count; columnCount++)
        {
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[(rowCount + 2), (columnCount + 1)] = dataTable.Rows[rowCount][columnCount].ToString();
            excel.Columns.AutoFit();
        }
    }

    string fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\ExcelData.xlsx", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The file '{0}' is saved successfully!", fileName));
}
```

Currently I'm using this solution to add datatable entries into an Excel sheet, but I want to add the entries in one go. I don't want to add cell by cell. Is there any way to add entries in one go? How do I add bulk data to an Excel sheet?

Comment: you should use http://epplus.codeplex.com/  its great lib. for spreadsheet.

Comment: we cannot use third party dll or any interface

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [this library](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

I understand it is a third party library and you are not allowed to use it. But they have uploaded the source code as well. I personally haven't gone through the entire source myself but I hope you might find something useful. The library is neatly broken down into pieces (cells, rows, sheets, workbooks etc.). You can try to imitate and tailor the code according to your needs. Good luck.